# Node.js programm using (Firebase) appears to lock when inserting data in a loop

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref().child('documents/events');
for (var i = 0; i < eventList.length; i++) {
    let obj = eventList[i];
    let objBasicFields = ParseGeneralFields(obj);
    let AllFields = parseEvents(objBasicFields, obj);
    ref.child(AllFields["id"]).set(AllFields);
}
```

Because firebase is a real time database i would expect the program to just insert the data and move on with the loop. Instead it inserts the first row and than doesn't continue.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem. Right now the `parseEvents`, `objBasicFields`, `ParseGeneralFields` and `eventList`) are all unknown to us. Try to reproduce the problem with the simplest possible code, using hard-coded values. That will allow us to reproduce your problem, and makes it much easier to help.

Comment: What do you mean by "appears to lock"?  How are you observing this?  Have you tried adding logging at various points to see how your code is executing?  Does anything actually get added to the database?